# Can't use font-face in inline CSS for email template

Tags: css, email, fonts, inline, font-face

I want to apply a font-family, which is located on my server to my emails, which will be sent to a user via a form. The styling works via inline CSS in the email-template. I tried creating font faces, which are linking to the woff and woff2, but it didn't work:

```
@font-face{font-family:MuseoSlab;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(/assets/fonts/MuseoSlab300.woff2) format(\"woff2\"),url(/assets/fonts/MuseoSlab300.woff) format(\"woff\")}
```

Comment: I suspect that most mail user agents don't support Web fonts (@font-face).